# Pull to refresh default refresh level change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am using `UIRefreshControl`. I want to change its refresh action on pull down a tableview. When tableview slight pull down I need to refresh because my tableview has small height and I can't pull down enough to call refresh method.

**How can I change it?**

I simply added `UIRefreshControl` as below:

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
_refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.tweetTable addSubview:self.refreshControl];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: Maybe I undestand something wrong.. but did you just asked and answered a in the same post?

Comment: No...not answered...i just show my code. I need to know how can i do?

Comment: Try checking scrollView's contentOffset inside `scrollViewDidScroll` function

Comment: is it not possible with UIRefreshControl?

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: not fix but more than 30

Comment: so table view is not full screen but just small part of the screen

Comment: yes...so pull down not enough to call UIRefreshControl's action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I do not think you can change the behaviour of how much distance you have to travel to initiate the refresh I would just trigger it manually when user scrolled enough, something like:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard !refreshControl.isRefreshing else {
        return//do nothing if we are already refreshing
    }

    //set your threshold to whatever feels ok (I used -30 here)
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < -30 {
        refreshTable()
        refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
    }
}
```

You also might have to play a bit with offsetting table view properly when refresh is active so that the `UIActivityIndicator` is above your cells, and then adjust it again when you finish refreshing. Note you will have to call `refreshControl.endRefreshing()` in `refreshTable()` method once `API` calls are completed or whatever you are doing there...

Answer (score 1):

1) Implement the delegates `<UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>` in .h

2) Set your table's .delegate to self

3) Check the `scrollViewDidScroll` method (tableView will call it)

4) Observe the `tableView.contentOffset.y` value, and then, when it passes your desired threshold....

5) Manually adjust tableView using `setContentOffset:`MUCH lower to activate the refresh without user having to attempt to pull it that far.